# HTML5 notification with HTML elements inside

Tags: html5-notifications

How can I insert HTML tags inside the title and body of HTML5 notifications?

Comment: Not enough info . What kind of HTML notification?

Comment: @Cory I think OP is talking about HTML5 Desktop Notifications. See this.http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/. He want to how to format the `title` using html tags.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily *insert* HTML in both title and body:

```js
var notification = new Notification('<title>title</title>',{body:'<b>bold</b> content'});
```

But there’s no point: it won’t render. In Firefox, it’ll look like this:

[image: desktop notification with visible HTML]

The [spec says](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#body) that each of them is just a [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMString), and that means it’s just plain text.

If you care only about Chrome support, you might want to take a look at [Rich Notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/richNotifications). Otherwise, it seems we have to wait for some means to style desktop notifications.